# Use of Identifiers(underscore) in maps(JS)

Tags: javascript

I have encountered an interesting code in JS where factorial of an integer is calculated using pure functions. The code is as follows:

```
function factValues(n) {
return new Array(n-1).
fill(0).
map((_,i) => i + 2).
reduce((acc, e, i) => acc.concat([e*acc.slice(-1)[0]]),
 [1]);

}
```

So if I try factValues(6): i get the output:[1,2,6,24,120,760]

Can someone explain me the code? I didn't get it.

Comment: I get an error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at line 4**

Comment: `map((_ i)` is invalid ... did you mean `map((_, i)` - and clearly `map((i)` would be different, because `i` is now the first, not second, argument - arguments are positional, the name means nothing - there's a convention to use `_` for an "unused" argument - don't confuse that to mean `_` is in any way special

Comment: Okay.. thank you.. Can you give me any link or resource which explains more about this?

Comment: any javascript tutorial dealing with functions will explain this

Answer (score 1):

The underscore is being used as a placeholder. The syntax for `Array.map` is the following:

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
  // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

In this case, the function doesn't care about the currentValue and only needs the index. It's necessary to add the placeholder because otherwise it's not possible to use the index value.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the later part of the code ie. the use of reduce

Comment: Array reduce is documented too - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce